# Most readable way to assign a double quote to a string in C#

Tags: c#, string, quotes, readability

Does anyone else think that escaping characters in very short strings make them not very readable? I noticed I was using `s = "\""` in my code to assign a double quote a string, but having thought about it, I came up with the following alternative: `s = '"'.ToString()`.

- Is my alternative any good? Would you prefer see the first version in code?
- How would you go about assigning two double quotes (""), which might be `s = "\"\""`, to a string?

*/me is marking this CW before being pressured into it.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use:

```
String s = new String('"', 1);
```

or if you like to confuse people:

```
String s = @"""";
```

but actually I still prefer the good-old-fashioned escape: \"

Comment: I'd better get used to it then.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure the alternative is more readable, on the contrary it's confusing. Besides, using a function call to have a different look in the source code doesn't make much sense - I would even say it's bad practice.

The old-fashioned escape sequence is the best option IMHO.